# How do I modify an XML element using StAX in Java

Tags: java, xml, stax

I want to modify my name in xml cv file, but when I use this statement:

```
XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamWriter xtw = null;
xtw = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileWriter("eman.xml"));
```

all the content of the file are removed and it becomes empty. Basically, I want to open (eman.xml) for modification without removing its content.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to use STAX in processing your xml file , u should know that u can only read/write from/ to xml file , but if u want to modify ur xml when exact event happen in STAX u could make processing for ur xml using DOM . 
here is some example:

```
   XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
      XMLStreamReader xmlReader= factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        int eventType;
       while(xmlReader.hasNext()){
              eventType=  xmlReader.next();
              if(eventType==XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT)
              {
                  QName qNqme = xmlReader.getName();
               if("YURTAG".equals(qNqme.toString()))
                {
                DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                File file = new File("YOURXML.xml");
                Document doc = builder.parse(file);
                //make the required processing for your file.
```

`}

       }`

Answer (score 0):

The question about reading and writing at the same time with stax is also answered here: [How to modify a huge XML file by StAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479523/how-to-modify-a-huge-xml-file-by-stax/16991498#16991498)